# How do I get a yellow card back?

Tags: hearthstone

See the screenshot below. The red card backs I got from playing in the last season. How do I get the yellow ones?

[image]

Comment: Getting to legendary

Comment: @Lyrion: Legend is the [brown one](http://assets2.ignimgs.com/2014/02/26/2ajpg-720e22_960w.jpg).

Comment: I love this back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fireside Gathering.
You need to challenge a player on the same subnet as you 3 times while at least one additional player (3 total) is on the same subnet. There are sometimes real life gatherings where people meet to unlock this card back, but it also works with specific software or [network emulation tricks](http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/2436x4/hearthstone_fireside_cardback_easy_way/).

Answer (score 7):

http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/13665271/pull-up-a-chair-introducing-fireside-gatherings-5-8-2014
Here is the link from the battle.net
You need to clear 3 criteria

1. At least three people (including yourself) must be logged into Hearthstone on the same subnet.
2. Each match must be played against a player that is playing on the same subnet as you.
3. These matches can be played against your friends or using the Player Near Me feature, as long as the above two criteria are met.

Comment: Useless comment: "criteria" is already the plural of "criterion". So you mean "you need to meet three criteria". :D

Comment: Edited, thx Almo i didn't knew that

Comment: Sure! Glad you found the information useful. A lot of people hate finding these things out, for some reason. :)